# Alternative to FusedLocationProviderApi

Tags: android, api, location, location-provider, fusedlocationproviderapi

I don't want my app to rely on Google APIs. Are there any open source alternatives to FusedLocationProviderApi that allow to combine standard GPS and Network providers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be late, yet for any person asking this same question, this is a pretty good alternative: https://github.com/mapzen/lost

Comment: Unfortunately this library is no longer supported or maintained.